# inserting Item's ID into query string

Tags: c#, asp.net

Dear guys! I have list view and for each item there is a button. What I'm trying to do is: When user clicks the button he should be re directed to a page with a pair of Key/Vale of specified item in the new pages query string. like:
http:/newpage.aspx?ID=123456&...

Comment: Show some code Plus your efforts!

Comment: I have nothing in mind. I can do it with session but i want it to be inserted into query string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkView" runat="server" 
PostBackUrl='<%# string.Format("Pages/User/vFullSpecs.aspx?vID={0}", Eval("vID")) %>'>View Form</asp:LinkButton>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
private void ListView1_SelectedIndexChanged_UsingItems(
        object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
  if (listView1.SelectedItems.Count == 1)
  {
   string Myval =ListView1.SelectedValue;    //Assumeing this is your ID
   string MyText=ListView1.SelectedItems[0].Text
  Response.Redirect("http:/newpage.aspx?ID="+Myval );
 }
}
```

Comment: <asp:LinkButton runat="server" Text="Edit" PostBackUrl='<%# "~/Pages/User/vFullSpecs.aspx?vID=" + Eval("vID")%>'></asp:LinkButton>

Comment: Dear @Ganesh_Devlekar how can I get pair in new page and use it?